# How do I check if a particular field is set?

Tags: php

How do I check if a particular field is set or not ?

For example :

*html*

```
<form method="post" action="check.php">
  name <input type="text" name="username" /> <br />
  text to send <input type="text" name="to_send" /> <br />
  <input type="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
```

*php*

```
if(isset($_POST['username'])) {
    echo "Username is set";
}else if(isset($_POST['to_send'])) {
    echo "text-to-send is set";
}
```

No matter I enter something into the `username` field or not `if` statement always evaluates to `true`. Why is that ?

How do I check if a particular field is set or not ?

Comment: `var_dump($_POST)` and see what you're getting

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because most controls are always set even if empty (one exception is checkboxes).  Try:

```
if(!empty($_POST['username'])) {
```

Comment: okay but this is not working when there is more than one form on a web page.

Comment: Only one form will be submitted on a web page at a time.  Everything within the <form> open and </form> close tag will be in the post array.  Are you submitting more than one username field in the same form?

Comment: @LaytonEverson you didn't get me..The script is `if(!empty($_POST['username'])) {
  echo "Username is set";
 }else if(!empty($_POST['to_send'])) {
  echo "text-to-send is set";
 }else if(!empty($_GET['new_text'])) {
  echo "new-text is set";
 }else { echo "else block"; }`

Comment: @LaytonEverson when the field `new_text` belongs to a second form on the same web-page

Comment: @LaytonEverson and when I submit the second form, instead the `else` statement runs. Why is that ?

Comment: @LaytonEverson the second form uses `get` method to transfer data while the first form uses `post` to send data

Comment: @LaytonEverson The question has been answered, so I should not post another question into this one. Can we discuss this little problem here http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/39866/discussion-between-layton-everson-and-saplingpro

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
if(!empty($_POST['username'])){
  echo "Username is set";
}else if(...
```

Answer (score 0):

The field will always be set because it is a part of the post array coming from the submit action.  You actually need to check the field for a value other than "" or an empty string.

```
if($_POST['username'] == ''){
    //This field is an empty string
} else {
    //There is a value here
}
```

However, as stated above:

```
if(!empty($_POST['username'])){
```

is much more efficient, and the proper way of doing this.

Comment: Lots of wasted code here... PHP's `empty` is a much quicker and efficient option.

Comment: I think its important to illustrate the concept.

Comment: Plus, my answer wasn't wrong... down vote for that? You hurt my feelings.